# pandas contains regex

Tags: pandas

I would like to match all cells that beginns with 978 number. But following code matches `397854` or `nan` too.

```py
an_transaction_product["kniha"] = np.where(an_transaction_product["zbozi_ean"].str.contains('^978', regex=True) , 1, 0)
```

What do I do wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) will check if the regex occurs *anywhere* in the string.

If you insist on using regex, [`.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match) does what you want.

But for this simple case [`.str.startswith("978")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas.Series.str.startswith) is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from regex, you can use .loc to find cells that start with '978'. The code below will assign 1 to such cells in column 'A', just as an example:

```
df.loc[df['A'].astype(str).str[:3]=='978', 'A'] = 1
```

note: astype(str) converts the number to string and then str[:3] gets the first 3 characters, and then compares it to '978'.